# Can I use a card from Eighth Edition in Modern Format?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-modern

If I'm playing Modern Format, can I use an Eighth Edition *Air Elemental*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Eighth Edition cards are [legal in Modern](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/modern).

Air Elemental is [legal in Modern](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Printings.aspx?multiverseid=45255), no matter what set it's from<sup>[1]</sup>, because it's found in a legal set.

While this isn't relevant to Air Elemental (since its text never changed), keep in mind that the text printed on the card is irrelevant; one always uses the Oracle text and other information found in Gatherer to determine the characteristics of a card.

---

1. Subject to the [usual requirements](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/19015/2880).